# java.net.SocketException: socket closed on android

Tags: android, sockets, wifi-direct

I am using socket to send image from server to multiple client but after sending one image to every client again when i try to send another image it say socket is close but i didn't even  close the socket as well.

So i want to keep my server and client socket is alive until the activity is visible.

I am using service to run socket server after that i am getting all socket list to activity so below is my code for server side

```
   if (mBoundService != null) {
            mSOcket = mBoundService.getSocket();

            //fetching all connected client socket list to broadcast all
            mSocketArraylist = mBoundService.getSocketArrayList();

            if (mSocketArraylist != null) {

                for (int i = 0; i < mSocketArraylist.size(); i++) {
                    Socket mSocket = mSocketArraylist.get(i);
                    try {
                        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(mSocket.getOutputStream());
                        ContentResolver cr = mContext.getContentResolver();
                        InputStream is = null;
                        try {
                            is = cr.openInputStream(Uri.parse(data.getData().toString()));
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
                        }
                        copyFile(is, out);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            } else {
                Log.e("Socket value", "Socket is null");
                Thread.interrupted();

            }

        }

public static boolean copyFile(InputStream inputStream, DataOutputStream out) {
    byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    try {
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        out.close();
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

For client also i am using service below its implementation

```
 class clientThread implements Runnable {


    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (wifiInfo != null) {
            if (!wifiInfo.isGroupOwner) {
                String host = wifiInfo.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress();
                Socket clientSocket = new Socket();
                OutputStream os = null;

                try {
                    clientSocket.bind(null);
                    clientSocket.setKeepAlive(true);
                    clientSocket.connect((new InetSocketAddress(host, port)), SOCKET_TIMEOUT);

                    os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os);

                    final File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                            + SocketClientService.this.getPackageName() + "/VR-" + System.currentTimeMillis()
                            + ".jpg");


                    File dirs = new File(f.getParent());
                    if (!dirs.exists())
                        dirs.mkdirs();

                    f.createNewFile();

                    while (true) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "server: copying files " + f.toString());
                        InputStream inputstream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
                        copyFile(inputstream, new FileOutputStream(f));
                        break;
                    }

                    signalActivity(f.getAbsolutePath());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());

                }

            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "This device is a group owner, therefore the IP address of the " +
                        "target device cannot be determined. File transfer cannot continue");
            }

        }
    }
}
public static boolean copyFile(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream out) {
    byte buf[] = new byte[8192 * 8192];
    int len;
    try {
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
       //            out.close();
      //            inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

So any one can help me out in this , help would be appreciated.

Comment: A more robust solution would be to use Firebase Cloud Messaging to notify clients that a new image is available then for each client open a socket to the server to pull down the image and close the socket following completion

Comment: i am doing with out internet

Comment: In that case maybe do a regular poll from the client i.e. periodically open a socket to the server which either returns image or nothing changed message then close the socket

Comment: actually i didnt close the socket

Comment: My previous comment was an attempt at another way of achieving the same functionality without trying to keep the socket open which is tricky